# Select function and table columns on a single SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I did some searching but couldn't find any examples.

Is there a way to query multiple columns from **both** tables and **a function call** while using SQLAlchemy Core?

This is the query I want to achieve:

```sql
SELECT
    t.id, t.field_1, t.field_2,
    some_function(t.field_2, t.field_3).*
FROM my_table t
```

Where `some_function` is a function that returns a 3-tuple, say `calc_field_1`, `calc_field_2` and `calc_field_3`

The resulting set should be a table like so:

| id | field_1 | field_2 | calc_field_1 | calc_field_2 | calc_field_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 3 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible to change original SQL to this

```
SELECT
    t.id, t.field_1, t.field_2,
    calc_field_1, calc_field_2, calc_field_3
FROM my_table t, some_function(t.field_2, t.field_3);
```

then it's possible to express on Sqlalchemy Core

```
stmt = (
    select([
        my_table.c.id,
        my_table.c.field_1,
        my_table.c.field_2,
        column('calc_field_1'),
        column('calc_field_2'),
        column('calc_field_3')
    ])
    .select_from(my_table)
    .select_from(func.some_function(my_table.c.field_2, my_table.c.field_3))
)
```

Currently (as of Sqlalchemy 1.3) docs suggest that [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.columns). Sqlalchemy 1.4 (in beta) should provide [table valued functions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.table_valued)

---

If you can't move the function to the `FROM`-clause, then..

```
from sqlalchemy import literal_column
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Grouping
stmt = (
    select([
        my_table.c.id,
        my_table.c.field_1,
        my_table.c.field_2,
        Grouping(
            func.some_function(my_table.c.field_2, my_table.c.field_3)
        ).op('.')(literal_column('calc_field_1')).label('calc_field_1'),
        Grouping(
            func.some_function(my_table.c.field_2, my_table.c.field_3)
        ).op('.')(literal_column('calc_field_2')).label('calc_field_2'),
        Grouping(
            func.some_function(my_table.c.field_2, my_table.c.field_3)
        ).op('.')(literal_column('calc_field_3')).label('calc_field_3'),
    ])
    .select_from(my_table)
)
```

it will produce the following SQL

```
SELECT t.id, t.field_1, t.field_2,
  (some_function(t.field_2, t.field_3)) . calc_field_1 AS calc_field_1,
  (some_function(t.field_2, t.field_3)) . calc_field_2 AS calc_field_2,
  (some_function(t.field_2, t.field_3)) . calc_field_3 AS calc_field_3
FROM my_table t
```

And a shorthand operation:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import functions

class some_function(functions.GenericFunction):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return Grouping(self).op('.')(column(key, String))

stmt = (
    select([
        my_table.c.id,
        my_table.c.field_1,
        my_table.c.field_2,
        some_function(my_table.c.field_1, my_table.c.field_2)['calc_field_1'].label('calc_field_1'),
        some_function(my_table.c.field_1, my_table.c.field_2)['calc_field_2'].label('calc_field_2'),
        some_function(my_table.c.field_1, my_table.c.field_2)['calc_field_3'].label('calc_field_3'),
    ])
    .select_from(my_table)
)
```

Solution is taken from [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/3555), checked with postgresql

Comment: Thanks for replying. I saw examples like that, but will that have the same effect, though? Will `some_function` be called for every row in the query?

Comment: Tried that suggestion, and PostgreSQL complains: `ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in functions in FROM`. I'll try with MySQL as soon as possible, but I suspect it won't be possible either.

Comment: Thanks again @inf581. I'm sorry for this kind of noob question, but won't that force the function to be called three times?

Comment: It depends on your function and database, if the function is deterministic, then its execution plan may be cached. You can always check execution plan of the resulting query on your database to be sure.